# How Dynamically Chnage the height of webview According to HTML text

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiwebview

I want increase the size of webview,row according to Html text,but my web view size is not getting correctly,Intially i am showing the content in fixed frame,later when user selects row i need to expand the cell accoriding to html text,please help me in solving this,the code which i used is

```
enter code here  NSLog(@"web view and selected ==== %d ---%d",webView.tag,selectedRow);
//CGFloat webViewHeight = 0.0f;
if (webView.subviews.count > 0) {
    UIView *scrollerView = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    if (scrollerView.subviews.count > 0) {
        UIView *webDocView = scrollerView.subviews.lastObject;
        if ([webDocView isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIWebDocumentView") class]])
            webViewHeight = webDocView.frame.size.height;

        NSLog(@"web view height is %d",webViewHeight);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual HTML document height, you should do:

```
NSUInteger height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getDocHeight()"] intValue];
```

where `getDocHeight` is:

```
function getDocHeight() {
  return Math.max(
    Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight),
    Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight),
    Math.max(document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
  );
}
```

For this to work, you will have to wait for the HTML document to have been fully rendered (i.e., your delegate received `webViewDidFinishLoad:`).

P.S.: if you want to do a quick check you could also simply try:

```
    NSUInteger height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight"] intValue];
```

this should also work, but the above version is more portable.